# Creating another group for rigid bodies

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody, cache

I have no idea how to create another group for rigid bodies. My animation involves several meshes becoming rigid bodies at different points in time.

I know there is a starting rigid body group named RigidBodyWorld, but no other groups are automatically created. I can't find the answer to this anywhere. I only intend for the rigid bodies themselves to start moving one after the other, so they aren't moving at the same time.

The reason I need different groups is so that the rigid bodies have different caches, and can move at different times.

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Unfortunately your question is not very clear. Maybe describe in detail a little example what you really wanna make. e.g. a ball should fall from coordinate 0,0,10 at frame 10, another ball should fall from the same coordinate at frame 50. That would be clear. Your description is a bit indistinct. That's the reason why no one answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the rigid body settings, you can choose/select collision collections. Note: you can select more than one collision collection.

Hope that helps.

[image]